# Delete attribute from model produced after query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I execute a query using `find_by_sql` and one of the attributes I return is the `count(*)`. But I want to just extract the count for a different variable and delete it from the models returned. Here's an example of the query:

```
Model.find_by_sql("select prop1, sum(prop2), count(*) OVER() AS full_count from table 
                   group by prop1
                   limit 3")
```

I get an array of `Model` with the attributes (`Model.attributes`) like this:

```
[{prop1: "A", prop:3, full_count: 20}, {prop1: "B", prop:4, full_count: 20}, {prop1: "C", prop:6, full_count: 20}]
```

And that's what gets rendered to the front end.

But basically I'm going to store the `full_count` attribute in one variable and I want to delete it from the objects in the array. So I'd want the results to be:

```
[{prop1: "A", prop:3}, {prop1: "B", prop:4}, {prop1: "C", prop:6}]
```

I tried doing this:

```
query_result.each do |obj|
   obj.attributes.delete('full_count')
end
```

But that didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I tried searching but did not find anything that worked.

Comment: You can ignore the attribute if you do not want to use. How are you using the object? Rendering json? If so, you can ignore using except https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/to_json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are rendering as JSON you could do this

```rb
query_result = Model.find_by_sql("select prop1, sum(prop2), count(*) OVER() AS full_count 
                                  from table 
                                  group by prop1 
                                  limit 3")

full_count = query_result.first.full_count

query_result.as_json(except: :full_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
query_result = Model.find_by_sql("select prop1, sum(prop2), count(*) OVER() AS full_count from table 
                   group by prop1
                   limit 3")

result = query_result.map do |obj|
           obj.attributes.slice('prop1', 'prop')
         end
```